# save for an addendum offered as a tip - what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/08/15/ferguson-riots-play-big-in-russia/

> Little in the state television reports is left to conjecture, **save for an addendum offered as a tip to President Obama**: that the Ferguson riots may not just be local, but have already become a national problem.

I can't understand what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part do you not understand?  I see three elements that may cause confusion.

*Save for* is used as a synonym for *Except for*.
An *addendum* in this case is an extra comment at the end of the original piece.
A *tip* in this case is a suggestion.

So the sentence suggests that the reporter has added a suggestion to the end of the report.