# Meaning of "save insofar"

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence which I couldn't understand the exact meaning.

> "Save insofar as the contract may prescribe"

May I get it in different words please?

Comment: Please provide context and/or a source so we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler wording might be:

> Unless the contract says something else, ...

or

> If the contract does not say anything contrary [to what follows the comma], ...

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase this sentence would be:

> Except to such an extent as the contract may write

This alone doesn't make sense so I assume that there is a previous sentece.

Comment: I suggest you might want to paraphrase *save*, too, as *except*; this sense of *save* is unlikely to be familiar to learners.

Comment: As seen [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31552/save-for-an-addendum-offered-as-a-tip-what-does-that-mean?rq=1) and [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43979/save-for-meaning?rq=1) for example.

Comment: @WBT in a way I am asking for more context in the question so I can improve my answer. I am aware that there should be a phrase that goes before and/or after it.

Comment: @CipherBot Asking for more context is the function of a comment on the question, not an answer.   Samuel Lijin sets an example here and you can upvote his comment if you like.

Comment: @WBT Of course I know that it should be in a comment but as I said, just an assumption nothing else. This _could_ also be interpreted as asking for more context.